# Video does display in android emulator

Tags: java, android

Video does not display while I run the Project. I also push a.mp4 file in File Explore -> mnt -> sdcard -> a.mp4 still videos not play while run the project. Please anyone help me where is mistake in below code.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    VideoView video_player_view;
    SurfaceView sur_view;
    MediaController media_controller;
    DisplayMetrics dm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void getInit()
    {
        video_player_view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        media_controller = new MediaController(this);
        dm = new DisplayMetrics();      
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int height = dm.heightPixels;
        int width = dm.heightPixels;
        video_player_view.setMinimumHeight(height);
        video_player_view.setMinimumWidth(width);
        video_player_view.setMediaController(media_controller);
        video_player_view.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/a.mp4");
        video_player_view.start();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Have U Restart Emulater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U didnt call the getInit() method

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    VideoView video_player_view;
    SurfaceView sur_view;
    MediaController media_controller;
    DisplayMetrics dm;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);\
   getInit();
    }

  public void getInit()
    {
  video_player_view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
  media_controller = new MediaController(this);
  dm = new DisplayMetrics();      
  this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
  int height = dm.heightPixels;
  int width = dm.heightPixels;
  video_player_view.setMinimumHeight(height);
  video_player_view.setMinimumWidth(width);
  video_player_view.setMediaController(media_controller);
  video_player_view.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/a.mp4");
  video_player_view.start();  
   }
  }
```

The emulator does have issues playing some videos, so I have always done all video testing on actual devices. When video does work on the emulator, it is typically extremely slow (1fps, offset sound) at best.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getInit() {
    video_player_view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    media_controller = new MediaController(this);
    dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    int width = dm.heightPixels;
    video_player_view.setMinimumHeight(height);
    video_player_view.setMinimumWidth(width);
    video_player_view.setMediaController(media_controller);
    video_player_view.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/a.mp4");
    video_player_view.start();
}
```

You have to call `getInit()` from `onCreate()` of your `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the call to `getInit()`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
VideoView video_player_view;
SurfaceView sur_view;
MediaController media_controller;
DisplayMetrics dm;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);\
    getInit();
}

public void getInit()
{
    video_player_view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    media_controller = new MediaController(this);
    dm = new DisplayMetrics();      
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    int width = dm.heightPixels;
    video_player_view.setMinimumHeight(height);
    video_player_view.setMinimumWidth(width);
    video_player_view.setMediaController(media_controller);
    video_player_view.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/a.mp4");
    video_player_view.start();  
 }
}
```